# @future solves ERROR: MIXED_DML_OPERATION but Batch fails

Tags: apex, batch, dml

A user is automatically created in the backend whenever a contact is created in the sf console. A custom field, DivisionCs is filled during that automated process. We want the same field to be updated in the contact too. I've created a trigger and it calls the following apex class to do the job. We've also planned to run a batch once to update all the contacts.

```
public class TriggerCUClass {

    public static void CUMethod(User updatedUser) 
    {
        String strDivisionCs;
        String strUserEmail;

        strDivisionCs = updatedUser.DivisionCs__c;
        strUserEmail = updatedUser.Email;

        List<Contact> con = [SELECT Id, DivisionCs__c FROM Contact WHERE email =: strUserEmail LIMIT 1];

        if(con.size() != 0) {
            con.get(0).DivisionCs__c = strDivisionCs;
            update con;
        }    
     }
 }
```

This code is working when I modify User object fields but the issue is I'm not able to make a user inactive as it throws an Error: MIXED_DML_OPERATION as it is an operation between the User(setup) and the Contact(non setup) objects. I’ve also created a batch class that calls the previous class which is executed and updates all the contacts successfully.

To overcome the MIXED_DML_OPERATION, I've modified the code as given below, using a method with future annotation to make an asynchronous web service. Now I can make a user inactive and make any other changes to the user and the field in the contact gets updated.

```
public class TriggerCUClass {

    public static void CUMethod(User updatedUser)
    {
        String strDivisionCs;
        String strUserEmail;

        strDivisionCs = updatedUser.DivisionCs__c;
        strUserEmail = updatedUser.Email;

        CUUpdate(strDivisionCs, strUserEmail);  
    }

    @future
    public static void CUUpdate(String strDivisionCs, String strUserEmail) {
        List<Contact> con = [SELECT Id, DivisionCs__c FROM Contact WHERE email =: strUserEmail LIMIT 1];

        if(con.size() != 0) {
            con.get(0).DivisionCs__c = strDivisionCs;
            update con;
        }
    }
}
```

But now the issue is I'm not able to run the batch class as the @future methods cannot be executed in a batch. Do I have to write a separate batch class without calling this class or what is the best way to proceed in this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, just do something like this

```
public void run_batch(ID i){ //This is called from batch
    //Code executed here
};

@future
public void run_future(ID i){ //This is called from trigger/class

    run_batch(i);

}
```

Comment: Hey @Eric, I'm trying with a few records and it's working fine. But I'm just curious to know, will it work when there are more than 10K records with @ future method?

Comment: @Seesh, Nope. You will most likely need to change the signatures to use List<ID> and modify the code to bulkify.

Comment: But the Batch for 10K records is not going to use the future method, it directly calls the run_batch method and executed the code. Even then we have to modify to bulkify?

Comment: @Seesh - Yes or you will hit governor limits. Not to mention all sorts of other potential issues with updating or querying records one at a time in a bulk transaction

Comment: Eric, I understand. I'm trying to modify the code for bulk transactions. So once I've coded, can I update in the post for you to scan it?

Comment: @Seesh - Do not post it in this thread. If you have specific issues with the code please start a new thread....

Comment: Got it.. sure..